# Why isn't it possible to view this user's profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

Someone [answered one of my questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/148184/131868), but it's not possible to click their name to view their profile. Why is that?

I've seen this sort of thing when a user has been deleted. But I looked at this answer literally one minute after it was posted. Could the user have been deleted within that one minute? It seems unlikely.

Comment: Looks like the user has been deleted.. I found two other deleted users, that have posted answers within the last 20 minutes. Probably some sort of spammer.

Comment: @Floern I see. This answer doesn't contain any spam, though the quality does seem low.

Comment: @Fiksdal Sockpuppet accounts are also often deleted. Also users can delete, or request the deletion, of their own accounts. I suppose in some super-egregious case, a non-sockpuppet non-spammer troll account might also get deleted by SE, above and beyond normal (long term or permanent) suspension, but at the moment I can't think of a reason for doing that.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for that info. What puzzles me here is that this user seems to have been deleted a very short time after they answered my question.

Comment: @Fiksdal Then either self-deletion, or a sock.

Comment: @DanBron Alright, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user's account has been deleted and removed.

That is why the profile is unavailable, the avatar is "missing", and the link is greyed out. Once a user has been removed, their profiles and avatars cannot be accessed nor seen respectively but their posts will stay.